# Call API Gateway from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call API gateway as a regular HTTP endpoint from a Lambda function, using http client from Node js. But I'm getting

> {
> "errorType": "Error",
> "errorMessage": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https:///test",
> "trace": [
> "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https:///test",
> "    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:71:26)"
> ]
> }

I don't have any type of authentication on the API Gateway itself, and the same call from Postman works as charm. Any idea on what I'm missing?

Comment: Is the lambda deployed in a VPC? Is it in a public or private subnet?

Comment: it is public. I tried another external endpoint and it does the job

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: It's deployed in a public VPC subnet? If so, that will prevent the Lambda function from accessing anything outside the VPC.

Comment: If it is in a public subnet another endpoint will not work either. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/ Having it in a public subnet at all makes little sense, have it in a private one with proper routing towards the internet or do not have it in a subnet / VPC at all.